# Query conditional parameters

Tags: mysql

I need to query to see if there are events found matching particular business on particular day of the week. However if there's only one event in the db that matches this business I want to display it anyway. Not sure how to incorporate this logic into my query.

```
$saturday = 6;

SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE busID = $busID
AND $saturday IN (t1.week_days)
```

t1.week_days is a comma-separated string: 2,3,4,5

Comment: If `t1.week_days` is a comma-separated list you should be using `FIND_IN_SET`, not `IN()`.

Comment: You also should avoid putting comma-separated lists in tables.

Comment: @GrantWinney Exactly. Thx

Comment: What if there are no events on Saturday, and more than one event on other days?

Comment: @Barmar If there are no events for Saturday, but there are events for other days, show them.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't IN much faster than strict function FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: @santa `IN` requires a literal list in the SQL, it won't work with a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two queries, one for all events for the business, another for just the events on Saturday. Combine them with `UNION`, and then filter to the Saturday events if they exist.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 1 AS type, t1.*
      FROM t1
      WHERE busID = $busID
      AND FIND_IN_SET($saturday, week_days)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS type, t1.*
      FROM t1
      WHERE busID = $busID) AS x
HAVING type = MIN(type)
```

Comment: Just realized I have an additional param. Some users could've created events for different days, and normally when I match the day of the week I show that event. However, when there's no even on that particular day and I decide to show events from other days I want to restrict to one per user, who entered those events. For example, user=55 entered events for 2,3,4. I show on 5 and do not want to include all 3 events from user 55, but rather just one, any one. Any way to add that restriction?

Comment: Add `AND user = $userID` to the second query in the union, and add `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Why do I need "AS x" ?

Comment: Because every subquery needs an alias. Try without it and you'll get an error message.